# how to find the equation of a composite function given the graph of the function

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions

so i am given a graph for the function and asked to find an equation for the graph given only that the function is a composite of an absolute[image]

value function and a simple 3rd degree function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know IMMEDIATELY that there are $3$ zeros, by eyeballing the function --- and because we are given that it is a cubic.

(We know that $|0|=0$)

We have that the function is $y=c|(x+2)x(x-2)|$.

We also have that $f(1)=3$.

$3=c|3(1)(-1)|=c|-3|=c|3|$, so $c=1$ and our function is $\boxed{y=\big|(x+2)x(x-2)\big|}$, which is also equal to $y=\big|x^3-4x\big|$.